# Is there a way to read first N images , perform operations and read next N images from a folder which has multiple images in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm working with an Image processing algorithm which involves taking triplet of images to compare errors.Iam confused about the basic step of reading set of 3 images from a folder performing some operation such as feature extraction and reading next set of 3 images to perform operation and so on..

I wrote the code to extract first 3 images from 1500 images. In order to perform feature extraction I have to take triplet of images together as input to the algorithm, extract the features and store into a matrix. When I extract features from 3 images together,I need to get a feature matrix of 3*37 , Assuming I have 37 features.How do I get the feature matrix for all images?

```py
imageDir_meas = #specify your path here
image_path_list = []
valid_image_extensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".tif", ".tiff"] #specify your vald extensions here
valid_image_extensions = [item.lower() for item in valid_image_extensions]

#create a list all files in directory and
#append files with a vaild extention to image_path_list

for file in os.listdir(imageDir_meas):
    extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
     if extension.lower() not in valid_image_extensions:
        continue
    image_path_list.append(os.path.join(imageDir_meas, file))

for imagePath in image_path_list[:3]:
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)

    # display the image on screen with imshow()
    # after checking that it loaded
    if image is not None:
        cv2.imshow(imagePath, image)
    elif image is None:
        print ("Error loading: " + imagePath)
        #end this loop iteration and move on to next image
        continue
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if key == 27: # escape
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Once you obtain the full list of valid files in the directory, why not parse that list 3 elements at a time in a loop? Provide those 3 elements (filenames) to your feature extraction function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n_input = 3 # your algorithm needs 3 images
image_path_list_sub = [image_path_list[x:x+n_input] for x in range(0, len(image_path_list), n_input)]
for imagePath in image_path_list_sub:
    if len(imagePath) == 3:
        img0 = cv2.imread(imagePath[0])
        img1 = cv2.imread(imagePath[1])
        img2 = cv2.imread(imagePath[2])
        # your_algorithm(img0, img1, img2)
    else:
        continue
```